# TeX new site theme is live

Tags: discussion, design

We rolled out the new site theme for TeX. It is now live.

### What new theme?

If you're like, "What the heck are you talking about?", then you should read the Meta Stack Exchange post entitled [Rollout of new network site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312365/rollout-of-new-network-site-themes)  (and maybe the posts it links to for the full background).

### Your help needed

You are one of the first sites to get a new, unified theme. I [previously posted the designs for theme](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/new-tex-site-theme-coming-soon) in meta. The feedback given to that post was considered prior to rolling out the theme. Please help us look for issues/bugs and post the details (including images where needed) as an answer below.

If you have concerns or issues regarding the left nav then [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness) is the right place for feedback. If you have issues with any functionality that is unrelated to the new theme, then please post a new question.

Comment: As far as I can see, ***NONE*** of our suggestion has been taken into consideration.

Comment: badge completion indicator should be darker. I barely see the progress.

Comment: The new site is absolutely awful.

Comment: Looks as if StackExchange is over the hill.

Comment: If I knew this existed I wouldn't have ranted in chat about how the new site looks. Is it too late to propose the following changes to the new site design: *revert every change made from the previous* (yes, I read the other posts about the redesign beforehand)

Comment: "You are one of the first sites to get a new, unified theme": Please, don't spread the infection any further...

Comment: It has to be said the new theme is pretty bad, the only part of the screen of interest, the central part with the posts is squeezed into a narrow band, the left sidebar  is _far_ too wide and so almost entirely a waste of space and the right side bar with occasionally useful links is far too prominent. this is supposed to be a forum about typesetting and it looks like a complete design  disaster.

Comment: This “question” does not show up on the front page of http://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ (probably because it's so heavily downvoted) and it does not show up in the “Featured on Meta” sidebar (only the “TUGboat open-access survey” question shows up), so it is very hard to get to this one unless one knows it's there.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR A combined consequence of the ugly new theme and some rules of SE.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I've made a new Meta question containing a link which can be upvoted and serve as a proxy. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7820/

Comment: This community *almost never* downvotes threads when the score is already negative (the score usually stops at -1), so I believe this is a good indicator of how upset TeX.sx is with the Powers That Be.

Comment: Despite all, [required reading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314089/156248).

Comment: It should be written very huge on the top of page that users of this site do not represent the design used here, which is a **complete disaster** as David said..

Comment: The redesign is an unmitigated disaster.  You have here a large community who cares deeply about design: **Take their advice seriously.**

Comment: Joe, I appreciate SE and I know you are trying to keep your codebase under control across a growing family of sites.  I just want to let you know that, even though I'm not a major user here, I still miss the old background image behind the header.  The new one is very stark compared to what I remember of the old.  Is there any way to bring the old header graphics back, even if the rest doesn't change?  Thanks in advance for your time and consideration!

Answer (score 79):

None of our suggestions in [New TeX site theme coming soon](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/new-tex-site-theme-coming-soon) has been taken into consideration. None. You could have simply avoided asking about the changes and deploy them without notice.

Alternatively, the Meta post about the site change might have been:

> Dear users of TeX.StackExchange, in a few days our sites will become all the same as Stack Overflow, because we like that site's design. Best.

I dislike the new design with all my heart.

At least, could you make the code display as before? Now it's too tight and the coloring is awful.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### Previous and current

[image]
[image]

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree.

Comment: @egreg Something from a few minutes has changed: the color of the code. The bracket have the same color of the command and not red.

Comment: This is fixed. Check it out and let us know if there are any additional issues.

Comment: @JoeFriend Yes, that's fixed. But about the part you marked [tag:status-completed] in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7748/4427 you ignored essentially all of my suggestion, so [tag:status-declined] would suit better. My request here has essentially nothing to do with the site design, for which the staff ignored *every* suggestion from users: only a few cosmetic ones were implemented, about colors; everything that characterized the site's design has been removed.

Comment: @egreg Sorry. I applied [meta-tag:status-complete] to the wrong part of your answer. I've corrected that.

Answer (score 62):

There is a lot of real anger about the changes here, and I think it's important to convey *why* this is. I'm going to try to do that from my own point of view: as a moderator, I'm not at all happy with the way things have been handled by the Powers That Be. (I think [Rollout of new network site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312365/rollout-of-new-network-site-themes#comment1022335_312406) sums it up pretty well.)

We (the 'TeX-sx community') have always known that StackOverflow support the site for their own reasons, most likely as promotion for the 'main site' (StackOverflow itself). There's always been reasonable concern about the 'community building' statements from the Powers: at best these ideas are usually poorly handled. (For an example of this, see [Community effort in fixing the double backslashes issue](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7317/community-effort-in-fixing-the-double-backslashes-issue/7329#7329): many hours of effort by a small number of active users were needed to fix a problem introduced by the Power *that could have been fixed easily by them*, and which *fundamentally broke 1000s of answers*.)

It's quite clear that the TeX site falls into the 'Cadillac' set of network sites: we got set up several years ago and got a lot of design support when we graduated. So any design changes were always likely to be risky (detrimental) from a 'site improvement' sense: the old design wasn't broken. At the same time, I think most users can see that the network staff do have a complex task supporting the 'back end' of all of the sites, and can accept that some change will happen. What it needs to be is *properly explained*, *proportionate* and *actually informed by user opinion*.

The changes that have been made have been 'sold' as 'improvements for the network as a whole'. However, the reality is that there's nothing here for *us* or I suspect many other longer-established sites. Features that are useful for the main site or one or two other *very* large ones (SuperUser, ServerFault) don't make any positive contribution if you have under 100 questions per day. The Powers might imagine users using lots of network sites, but I doubt I'm alone in visiting basically just (this) one in any regular sense.

There are two fundamental problems with the changes. The first is the 'big picture': the three-column layout that uses up a lot of the screen space for 'filler'. I suspect that this makes sense if you are using a massive desktop monitor as one of a two- or three-screen setup, with your web browser maximised: in other words, the set up of a professional programmer using StackOverflow. I'm however not like that: I'm writing this on a 13" laptop with my browser window about 2/3 of the screen width. (I've disabled the left sidebar, too, precisely because the design *doesn't work*.) The fact that this change has been made and not rolled back *quickly* shows a total lack of *real* engagement with users. Telling us 'this will help you' is a non-answer to the criticism: the new 'features' we are being told we'll get are *totally useless*, at least as currently described.

The second aspect is the smaller changes to design. There's a suggestion that these are needed to bring the 'back end' of sites into line, but they feel *arbitrary* and *poorly implemented*. For example, there are no obvious technical reasons why we have to loose custom graphics for voting buttons. I can think of only two reasons for this. The first is that StackOverflow wants to make the sites look more similar for advertising reasons. The second is that newer sites won't be getting custom graphics for resource reasons, so those of us who already have them loose out as 'it has to be fair'. Crucially, neither of these *is anything to do with the community on this site*. If there are things that have to be done for management reasons, including balancing resource usage, then *tell people*: the network is full of people with a technical background, for goodness sake. (See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312404 for another place that things feel entirely arbitrary, from a non-TeX site.)

A boycott has been raised, and some people will doubtless walk away, primarily because of the completely tone-deaf approach of the Powers That Be here. (It shows yet again that all of the 'community building' stuff is so much guff.) I'm not about to walk away, but as a community we are lucky that there is TeX beyond TeX-sx: we do have an international user group, people with server experience, *etc.* So if some sense of listening doesn't happen, I would not be surprised if a truly 'community owned' Q&A were to be established. I'd certainly register for such a site.

So what should StackOverflow do? I think you need to *roll back the changes* (network-wide), and think about what message you are actually trying to put across. If you really believe in community building, then listen to users. Moreover, if there are corporate reasons that some changes have to happen, then front-up and say that: we can understand 'The company has to balance its books, and this will help by ....'. The design changes should have been made step-wise over a period, not all in one go with both layout and resources changing. The key is to *actually show you are listening*, and to recognise that *each site is independent* (see for example https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312406 pointing more-or-less exactly that for another site).

Comment: "each site is independent" -- I think this is a fundamental point on contention. I have [advocated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258233/156248) for the _opposite_ myself, in fact. Few SE sites _actually_ stand alone, in the sense that their scope does not intersect with any other SE site. I can only guess at SE's stance here, but the idea of people being "on the network" as opposed to "on multiples sites" has been getting more prominent over the years (despite the focus definitely being on [SO]). Now, that doesn't have to do anything with designs, per se, but hints at different mindsets.

Comment: @Raphael I was thinking specifically of 'community': things like the 'regulars', moderation approach, internal conventions, _etc._  All of the network sites rely on volunteer contributions, and particularly for regular 'authors', some sense the site(s) being their 'local' is I think important. As I've said, I can see why the Powers want more sense of 'StackOverflow network', but that's not the same as it being good for _any particular site_.

Comment: thanks for mentioning the backslash mess and the effort it took to fix it.  (i'm still not sure we got absolutely everything fixed.)  a lot of people have come to depend on this site for *accurate* and *useful* information, offered with a welcoming vibe.  things that detract from that could well turn the community against it, which would be a great shame.

Comment: I see that Shog9 has  confirmed in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314128/150061 that the 'big picture' changes are about how the staff want to address the need to have a saleable 'product': 'Teams' is currently the big idea, and it 'needs' the left bar.

Comment: While there have been complaints about the usability effects from other communities as well, my feeling from looking at the other site meta announcements is that these discussions were not as fierce and persistent as on this site. I'm wondering if that has to do with the demographics on other sites when it comes to 'power users' or just people with larger screens. I normally view this site in full screen on a 1920 by 1080 screen and have not really noticed and adverse effect, but when I resize my window I can certainly see what others are complaining about.

Comment: Another point is probably that people on this site are more passionate about design and typography and that the theme change really did not work very well for our overall look especially compared to what we had before. All the blue just did not fit in, boxes appeared where they were absent before, the serif/sans serif combo looks off now ... Looking at https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312365 almost all themes but ours and Mi Yodea actually look kind of OK with blue boxes and sans serif. And the Mi Yodea theme has not been rolled out yet ...

Comment: Finally, I personally am unhappy with how the feedback to https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7743/35864 was handled. While the suggestions were quickly acknowledged we did not hear back about the progress on those issues. Then the theme was rolled out without warning and while the background issue and the link colours in the right sidebar were addressed, most other things were not and some things actually got worse (the initial background colour) than the mock-up screenshots shown in the announcements. That certainly did not make me feel that my feedback was valued.

Comment: @moewe I hope it's come across in my answer that I can live with the 'small' design changes, certainly if we get some sense of the clashing elements getting settled. As you say, it's the _handling_ of feedback and lack of a sense of listening that's a problem. And the 'responsive' layout is truly dreadful on a smaller screen unless one disables the left bar.

Comment: @moewe I think it's also notable that we are one of the 'Cadillac' sites: we had one of the best/most complete designs. So the changes 'hurt' us more than a lot of other places. I wonder how _e.g._ Photography and UX will react when they get it!

Comment: Yes, the 'Cadillac' thing is something I only started to realise when this whole re-theming thing started. We were indeed extremely lucky to have such a nice design that was thought through and designed with community feedback. I guess theme-wise (not sidebar/usability-wise) UX and Photo should be fine, blue would fit their colour schemes (maybe not so much on Photo which is more black/grey than blue) and they are sans-serif only. Photo has bracketed tags, not sure if they attach as much sentimental value to those as we do with `{ ... }`, UX has boxed tags.

Comment: ... Our theme was special insofar as that it did not really work with blue and the new sans-serif elements. The boxes and losing nice customisations for tags and upvote buttons (which I can accept but not really understand, your two hypotheses about the why have occurred to me as well) did the rest.

Comment: @moewe The Photo site has a custom top area that shows 'Picture of the Day': pretty important for them, and they presumably will loose that ... On the UX site, I was thinking more about how they'll view the three-column layout!

Comment: They have found a way to preserve that https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5714. I guess outrage would have been there had they lost it.

Comment: @moewe And this outrages me: why could we preserve *no* feature that made our site unique?

Comment: @egreg Well, at least we have our warm colour scheme. But I absolutely agree that we have lost quite a few things that made this site unique and that the *why* has not been communicated and motivated clearly.

Comment: I use a 12.5" laptop. I consider this large. My last was 11.6". I never use any windows full screen. Of course, I've disabled the left side bar because it just doesn't work. Now it is 2 clicks to view Questions rather than 1. The design has exaggerated all the very worst elements of the previous design, which already contain far too much wasted space, Even the warm colour scheme would be better jettisoned, in my opinion if we can't have a consistent palette. If we must have bright blue and violent astroturf green, better a theme to contain them. Never thought I'd get this mad about a website.

Answer (score 53):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

## Width of main content

[image]

*Added .gif by @Milo*

[image]

I realise the middle section is just the boring bit where the users chat about their interests and the sidebars are the interesting places where stackexchange can insert revenue earning links, but really is it too much to ask that a question and answer site leaves more room for the questions and answers?

The image shown is with the browser not full screen but not at a particularly unusual width, full screen the question/answer posts are still cramped with space lost to the more or less useless left bar and apparently completely dead space to the left of the left sidebar

[image]

I've just focused on the column layout here but other aspects mentioned in other answers such as colouring, and ugly boxing make the site a *lot* less pleasant to use than it was previously.

Comment: I agree the middle column in the first screenshot is uncomfortably narrow. But if I make my browser window a bit smaller the right bar disappears and I get ~110 characters. If I expand the window to match the second screenshot, I get ~110 characters again. I've read [50-75 is ideal for readers](https://baymard.com/blog/line-length-readability), so the middle column seems a bit big. Of course that rule of thumb might not hold when the page has some code or an image. Maybe it would help to show something other than the question lists to illustrate your concern?

Comment: @JonEricson you can make the window different sizes, but it's your css and it's making the columns that size in that window. Given that nearly all posts in the centre have code or an image it is simply too narrow even at full screen.  If you drag the window wider and narrower it's clearly visible that the sidebar widths are preserved until the last minute (when as you say it does drop the right bar) but the central content is distorted, this is just prioritizing things in completely the wrong order, you should fix an optimum width for the _main content_ and preserve that as far as possible

Comment: @JonEricson I'm not going to constantly adjust window widths for SE. I have multiple tabs open always with different sites. I expect sites to adjust to the window width available, because I can't set the width separately for each tab, even if I had the time to do it. I'm using a laptop screen and I have a small laptop. Space is at a premium and at least 50% of the space in your tabs is empty. 'It looks fine if you fiddle to get exactly the right pixel dimensions each time you visit the site' is, frankly, laughably weak. The only thing I want to do when I visit TeX SE now is stop looking at it.

Comment: @JonEricson On every site across the Stack Exchange network this complaint is brought up. Even sites notorious for narrow columns like (say) medium.com, have at least 75 characters for their text as you make window narrower, while here on TeX.SE we see fewer than 60 characters. Try it yourself: starting with a wide window, make it narrower until the right-bar disappears, then slightly wider so that it appears again: you'll see something like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc29t.png or  https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNxD6.png or https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eTAh.png — too narrow columns for the main text.

Comment: @JonEricson really the site is unusable with medium width windows (across the whole network) you need to back this out until you come up with  behaviours that preserves the main content width and shrinks or drops the sidebars as required. The code block styling and ugly boxes can be improved again over time, but you need to make the site usable first.

Comment: Indeed, as @DavidCarlisle says the main content has to be the priority. Notably, on the mobile version of the site, it's *only* the main content that gets served, with no sidebars at all!

Comment: @JonEricson Actually, as your comment started with “I agree the middle column in the first screenshot is uncomfortably narrow”, then shouldn't that be fixed? The fact that things are better at narrower or wider window widths doesn't change the fact that things need to be fixed for *this* width too. (The fix would be simple too; it's just a matter of increasing the minimum width at which the right bar appears… so the only reason for leaving it this way is that you indeed think it's better to have the right bar at this width, but you yourself said you *don't* think that. So it's puzzling.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the feedback. Responsiveness is a work in progress. The vast majority of users currently use the sites in view ports as large or larger than our max size. Even with the left nav pinned, the max size increase is not a problem for these users. With the left nav unpinned the max size is the same as before the change. Of course, for the percentage of folks who use a smaller window are impacted (some for the good, some not). This is a balancing act and is a work in progress. Hiding the left nav and right side bar more aggressively is something we are looking into.

Comment: If you switch off the CSS altogether, the width is great and, actually, the site is rather more usable in many ways with no CSS. It is pretty ugly, but the dominant green boxes even disappear. Unfortunately, stuff seems to get randomly superimposed on the content at the far left of the window, which is obviously a disadvantage. Still, it is as viable an option as any other, I'd say, at least for browsing the lists of questions. (Haven't tried viewing a question that way, so that might not work as well.)

Comment: @JoeFriend sorry that really is not an acceptable response. Even at _full screen_ the central content is too narrow and preserving the sidebars at the cost of distorting the posted content is frankly an insult to those of us who have freely given thousands of hours of our time to supporting this network. Please see our site mod Joseph's summary just posted. You should back this change out _now_ and come back with a usable design when you have one.

Comment: @JoeFriend I'm using the site (with the left bar enabled) in full size on a wide monitor and the large right side bar simply looks unbalanced and odd. I have reduced it with some css to 20%.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not sure how you're evaluating the width of the center content area, but question lists are 735 pixels wide at full window size with the left nav compared with 728 on the old design. For a question page the main content has only changed 2 pixels at max window size. With the left nav hidden it is in the same ballpark. So, I'm honestly not sure how to evaluate your feedback since it seems to contradict the facts as I understand them. Now, maybe I'm missing some context. Posting pictures in an answer that show what you're describing may help.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Our right side bar is fixed in width due to the need to support specific ad sizes. This is less of an issue for some sites where we have no/limited ads. But it is critical for us to keep the company running.

Comment: @JoeFriend my perception is coloured by the fact that the initial image I showed is a typical view for me. Feel free to ignore the full with comment if it is really true that even with both sidebars it is unchanged. I have removed the left and restyled the right in my personal setup as otherwise the site was too painful to use. Even with image ads  in the right bar you could scale them or at narrow sizes drop them as you do on mobile

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually we can't scale down ads. We have to use industry standard ad sizes and can't change them or scale them. We do relocate the ad when the right side bar is dropped (this is most notable on Stack Overflow). However, it is unclear how that impacts ad performance since most people don't currently see that view. If we see that ad performance is not significantly impacted, then we could be more aggressive in hiding the right side bar and maintaining the main content column width. This is something we will continue evaluating.

Comment: @Joefriend li do realise that the company needs income but if you can't scale them you need to drop them or move them before the main content becomes unusable. You manage on mobile so a normal desktop window should not be a problem. Otherwise our most viewed meta answer is going to be telling people how to scale the right bar. If you do it you retain control which to be honest is better for everyone than lots of incompatible customisations floating around

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Understood. Thanks for your persistence in articulating your viewpoint. Please do know that we're listening.

Comment: @JoeFriend apart from any technical issues, this rollout has been a public relations disaster for the company. Yes you need to sell advertising space, but there used to be a conceit that the network was about building communities and communities offering self help. But the communities feel (and have been) ignored insulted and belittled in this whole process.

Comment: @JoeFriend Well I can't stand this width. Which means that I will either scale it with css or shrink the window so that the right bar collapse. Both gives a much better usability.

Comment: @JoeFriend note my comments were not aimed at you personally but just using your Id to `@` ping "the company", so I think it only fair if I  link here to [Shog9's helpful response in the linked chat site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46234753#46234753) But the fact remains that the default three column layout is not usable and people will either be forced to use user scripts to over-ride it, or some will leave the site, both of which are unfortunate.

Comment: @JoeFriend When you talk about the number of pixels for the central column, I think that's part of the problem you have understanding what people are saying. Here are some specs: `  dimensions:    1920x1080 pixels (277x156 millimeters)
  resolution:    176x176 dots per inch`. This means that the maximum width of the central column is 107mm. (But usually it will be significantly less.) How many characters per line do you think it reasonable to fit in 107mm? When you talk about 75 characters per line, I don't know what you mean: you have a set number of pixels. ...

Comment: How many characters that means is not something you get to determine. It depends on DPI, font size etc. etc. Are you assuming a standard DPI? If so, reality doesn't fit. And I don't even have an especially high DPI screen (not quad or retina or whatever it is). I regularly scale windows up or down or use weird font sizes to adjust for the many applications which use different assumptions. E.g. GTK applications need large font sizes to be even marginally readable (and I still scale Firefox up). QT applications (e.g. my TeX editor) need tiny font sizes. It's a mess, but can't be assumed away.

Comment: @JoeFriend There's been some confusion: the feedback here is not about full window size, where as you say, things are indeed fine. The feedback is specifically about the *minimum* possible width of the main content area, at certain window sizes. Specifically, if I visit https://tex.stackexchange.com/ in an incognito window, then the main div (`<div id="mainbar">`) has width 726px (or 728px) in a full-size window, which is perfectly fine! But as you start making the window narrower, its width reaches a minimum of 443 px, which is unreasonably narrow. The complaint is about the 443, not the 726.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR But whether it is perfectly fine depends on the resolution. Do you mean perfectly fine on a 'Retina' display or perfectly find on a 96 DPI setup or both?

Comment: @cfr Well at the widest setting it's no narrower than before (AFAIK), and no one complained earlier, so... relatively speaking.

Answer (score 46):

## Boycott this site until and unless the old look is restored! If it's not restored, let's say goodbye and good luck to this site entirely.

Why do I say this? It's because I suspect that the only way that the powers that be will ever respect and listen to our views is if we -- and especially the most active users -- state unequivocally that we refuse to go along with the awful changes that have been foisted on us.

I hereby announce that starting immediately, I will no longer contribute any answers, not respond to queries, not issue any welcome messages to new users, and not provide any other forms of input to TeX.SE until the site's old look is either fully or at least mostly restored. For the next week or so, I will stop by maybe once a day, to check if the old look has been restored. That's all I will do. If in a week or so nothing positive has happened, I will ask the admins to delete all of my 5000+ answers, to delete all of my comments on other postings, and to strike all of the 30,000+ votes I've cast of other folks' answers.

What's so special about me, you may ask? Not that much, in many ways. For what it may be worth, though, I've been quite active on this site for more than 7 years, and I recently became the user with the fifth-highest rep point total on TeX.SE. Once in a while, I happen to get a sappy message of praise from the powers that be, about how very much my contributions are valued. Well, let's see if this official valuation is sufficiently sincere to make the powers that be show even a tiny bit of regard for my opinions.

Comment: Alternatively, and perhaps more productively, could TUG host its own version (like MathOverflow)? Since all the answers are CC licensed they can be moved, and since the base of highly skilled TeX users is quite small, moving the site might actually be something that could be carried off.

Comment: @AlanMunn - Your suggestion is inspired! Moving all of TeX.SE's contents to a place hosted by TUG sounds very much like the thing to do.

Comment: I hope you won't leave the site over the design. I know it must feel like we aren't listening and we don't respect your opinions. Unfortunately, change is necessary in order to build other useful features. For instance, [custom question lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/1438) aren't possible unless we have some uniformity of design. Maintaining dozens of similar, but not quite compatible designs just won't work. (By the way, [I've been on the other side too](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1706/914).)

Comment: @JonEricson I think SE underestimates the value of unique site designs to user engagement and sense of community. And some of the new features are probably of lesser value to sites like our which get on the order of 75 questions per day. If many of our high rep users were to leave and move to an independent site,  the SE site quality would definitely decline. Unlike other sites, there aren't a vast number of people with equal skills to replace them. So it's not just that it "feels like" you're not listening. You're not really listening.

Comment: @JonEricson Well, you ignored **ALL** our suggestions but mine (which basically said that you should scratch all of these). I hope **YOU** are not surprised.

Comment: @JonEricson but even if you make all the sites similar (which i can see has some merit from the organisation side) there is no need to make them all unpleasant to use: the amount of space given to questions and answers compared to the more or less pointless left sidebar and at best secondary information in the right sidebar makes no sense, and if you don't use the browser full screen it gets _worse_ as you shrink the main content while preserving the right sidebar

Comment: @AlanMunn: We've been preparing for this change for a while internally. This stage has been the one I've dreaded the most because we know that people like their designs. But the 100 or so sites with no design right now will benefit tremendously. I'm not suggesting you like the tradeoff, but I hope you can see we made the decision that we think is best for the entire network. I also hope we'll be able to address some of the biggest pain points in the next few months. (Joe has already started planning and prioritizing.)

Comment: @JonEricson "best for the entire network" sounds all warm and fuzzy and something we're supposed to care about (kind of like "best for society"), but it's not. What's good for the entire network is what's good for SE as a company. Of course we don't deny that SE has been a useful resource to most of us, but please don't try to sell "good for the whole network" as something other than an business concern.

Comment: @JonEricson - The availability of 'custom question lists' is utterly irrelevant to me and to my willingness or ability to contribute to TeX.SE. The 'change is necessary' trope is embarrassing. Please spare us trite and meaningless bromides.

Comment: @JonEricson I can only repeat myself from the answer: "I understand that SE becomes an internet Titanic, but maybe this is just another reason why to quit it before it sanks." I hope you, the Powers, realize this. If I had SE stocks, I would be selling at this point like crazy.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I know the left bar isn't much use yet, but it's pretty important [phase III of custom question lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/1438). We have other ideas for that space once it's available for all the sites. I've pretty much gotten used to it on Stack Overflow. (That said, I know other employees who don't really like it.)

Comment: @JonEricson - So here we have the official confirmation: The pointless left-hand bar is here to stay. No regard whatsoever for the opinions of real contributors. The thing that matters -- the *only* thing that matters -- is that you guys can move on to 'phase III of custom question lists'. The fact that pretty much nobody on TeX.SE has any hankering for such lists is of simply no importance.

Comment: @Mico: Yeah, it makes me uncomfortable to say "don't worry about that thing you like getting taken away, but you'll love this other thing that doesn't exist yet". It would be a lot easier to say "this change is going to make a ton of money for us". Unfortunately, that's not true. The current design prevents us from making changes we feel are beneficial. Maybe we're making the wrong decision (and [not for the first time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation)).

Comment: @yo': As an employee, I've been concerned that we've been ignoring our user base in order to pursue revenue. For years it seemed like we were [ignoring our users without making revolutionary improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263675/1438). That's not my concern anymore. Maybe we will sink as a company, but I somehow don't think the right sidebar will be the iceberg that does us in.

Comment: @JonEricson You do realize that this is a conceptual problem, don't you? (Sorry, I don't get your point about "the right sidebar", I don't see myself mentioning it, but I may be wrong.)

Comment: @boycott.se-yo': I'm not sure what you mean by conceptual in this case. I see the problem as [loss aversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion). You had a great looking site and now you don't. Losing something hurts way more than gaining it. I sympathize. And yet, it makes me sad that several people have decided that boycotting the site will hurt us back. It's counterproductive to the discussion and makes it a lot easier for designers and developers to just ignore your concerns. (I should have said "this site's design won't be the iceberg", I suppose.)

Comment: @JonEricson look at the comments and answers in this post, they are not mostly complaining about _change_ (which is how you are trivializing them as people just used to what they had) they are complaining that the new design is simply awful and has a massive, negative,  impact on the usability of the site.

Comment: @AlanMunn Remember 'TUG' is actually Karl Berry plus Robin Laasko for admin, basically, plus the committee for some sense of direction. The real _work_ would still have to be done by for example Stefan

Comment: @JonEricson - I stand by my initial evaluation: You guys are grotesquely self-centered and arrogant. If actual users bother to make good, cogent arguments against the new, awful design, these efforts are doomed to having no effect whatsoever. At most, these arguments will be “considered” [!]. The *only* action that has any chance at all of getting your attention is we threaten to vote with our feet, i.e., to turn our backs on you and your colleagues. That’s what I’m fully prepared to do.

Comment: @JonEricson Maybe I'm unashamed if saying that people come to the site *because* they'll find answers by me or David or Mico or the other top users. Are you sure the site will stay the same if we leave? It's been a good time, perhaps it's the moment to go somewhere else. You've been basically saying: “You guys are right, but nobody can do anything about the problem, because it's already been decided upon”.

Comment: If there's any possibility of developing an alternative, we should try to do that. This site is never going to have the importance here that a dedicated site might have for us. SE has shown repeatedly that what we think doesn't matter. Let's go somewhere, if we can, where it does. I'm no @egreg or David or Mico. What I contribute is trivial in the extreme, but, if they'll have me, I'm off. And if they won't, I'm probably mostly off too. Whether I boycott or not doesn't really matter. I just have no motivation to browse questions now. I just want to leave when I'm here.

Comment: I should say, @JonEricson, that I'm not threatening anything. I'm just reporting a psychological fact. That is, I have just found I don't want to spend time on the site. I want to stop looking at it. It is glarey and icky and it bothers my eyes. It is harder to read and unimportant elements jump out of the screen, with hardly any space for interesting content. It doesn't engage. As I say, these are just observations and just mine. People differ. But I don't think you need boycotters to see reduced engagement, fewer answers, less traffic. The site sucks.

Comment: @JonEricson "But the 100 or so sites with no design right now will benefit tremendously." Seriously, no. Plain text with ASCII art instead of imgur images to show the issues is a better design than this. No design is better than this. I have one question: If TeX.SX doesn't change back again, please optimize the site to be usable with Lynx. This way everyone could enjoy the looks of it. (This is meant completely serious, Lynx display is a better design than this.)

Comment: @JonEricson - You wrote yesterday, "it makes me sad that several people have decided that boycotting the site will hurt us back. It's counterproductive to the discussion and makes it a lot easier for designers and developers to just ignore your concerns." What's *really saddening* is that your designers and developers have chosen to blatantly and consistently ignore our concerns *all along*. Let's not pretend otherwise. Users contemplating a boycott of TeX.SE is not the cause of, but merely the pained reaction to, the already-taken decision by the powers-that-be to ignore our views.

Comment: @JosephWright What about somewhere like OverLeaf? Could TUG (or non-TUG for that matter) persuade them to take something like this up? There should be ways for them to gain from such a partnership and they have resources (technical and financial) which TUG doesn't, while being much more focused on what interests us. Probably a daft idea, I realise, but I don't think it is realistic to expect TUG to take on this kind of project. But there are other possibilities: sites with a focus on TeX, which might see themselves as having much more to gain from us than SE ever will.

Comment: @cfr I'm not ruling anything out, I'm mainly thinking about the problem SE solves well: getting high enough up search results to help people who *don't already know about it*. That as much as anything is the challenge nowadays.

Comment: I think instead of boycotting, I'll just stop. Even when defending these choices, the attitude is pathetic. I really don't understand where this high horse comes from. You SE folks are riding a little pony and without the users you are bunch of nerds trying to teach us how to socialize.

Comment: @JosephWright OverLeaf has an increasingly high profile, especially now it has swallowed ShareLaTeX. And, after all, people who don't know *anything* about it don't have problems trying to use TeX. But, anyway, it was just a thought.

Comment: @cfr Sure: the content is all available, it's mainly a question of someone doing the work to set up a new 'place'.

Comment: @JonEricson Hi, I am just passing by just to remember the Powers That Be that *you completely ignored the [backslash issue](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7317/community-effort-in-fixing-the-double-backslashes-issue)*. A lot of users (from high ranked to newbies) have devoted a significant part of their online times to manually fix the codes in thousands and thousands of questions and answers solely caused by SE. I am sorry, Powers That Be. Do not give us the usual **we are listening** answer because we all know, from past interactions, that you are not. Not in the slightest.

Comment: @JonEricson Well, you're clearly still ignoring your userbase, so why are you doing it if not to pursue revenue? By the language and voting in this thread you'd think this is [meta.sf] or [meta.math.se], but no, you've managed to quasi-unanimously tick off mild-mannered TeX.SE in an [unprecedented way](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20score%3a..-2). I'm impressed and saddened.

Comment: @cfr Many SE communities (specifically, many of the sites' power users) are pretty unhappy with SE, Inc. I wish there was a sensible alternative that could work for any topic.

Comment: @egreg If one of you leaves, it won't affect the site much. If all of you top team who made the site what it is leave, that's another story. (I count myself as part of the “top team” on two SE sites, and for a while I've been staying more because there is no viable alternative than because I really believe in this network's long-term potential.)

Comment: I've removed some comments here where valid points seemed to have been lost a lot of tension. Summary of the conversion: one can see reasons that the network has to standardise elements of the CSS; on the other hand, that does not mean the design fundamentals should be bad. The attitude of the Powers That Be toward the user base is also of significant concern.

Comment: @JosephWright I don't see how. Care to explain some of them? I don't enjoy this continuous submission to hygienic attitude. You might want to exercise the same on the powers-that-be comments.

Comment: How about answering questions in chat? Much less reusable content to draw people in. I don't suggest this is a good long term solution. But what about a temporary strike? Not getting paid isn't a good long term solution either, but as a short term protest, it can work. And answering in chat let's you explain *why* you're not answering on the main site. I ask this because I'm finding myself in a chat room most of the time I'm on site. And some of that is answers to questions I started working on on the main site, but then fled from.

Comment: That is, SE won't listen. How about trying the wider TeX community who come here, but not enough to register what's going on at the moment. Get more people protesting the changes ... or thinking about alternative locations and resources ....

Comment: @cfr - Like you, I've decided to pretty much withdraw from TeX.SE. The new layout and the overall look of the website are both dreadful. I simply no longer enjoy "being" on this site. I won't ask the moderators to close out my account entirely, though, as that would inflict a massive loss of rep points on others, especially as I've cast more than 30,000 votes over the past 7+ years. Time to move on. Who knows, maybe a better, competing site can be organized in the not too distant future.

Answer (score 40):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## The background image

*See [the original discussion](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7744/128068) about the background image (from [New TeX site theme coming soon](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/new-tex-site-theme-coming-soon))*

There was some discussion about the placement of the background picture in the site mockups. In the mockups, the header design was squeezed into the right hand corner. This made it difficult to recognise the writing/symbols because they were very small.

This size issue has been addressed in the latest redesign, and the header image has been made bigger and placed more centrally. However, in its current form, it's actually *impossible* to recognise the writing/symbols because they have nearly all been partially cut off.

**The new site**

[image]

**Compare it to the original site** - where the writing/symbols are not cut off.

[image]

The new site design has a thinner header than before. Trying to squeeze the old design into this space seems unsatisfactory because elements get cut off. So perhaps a new design is needed for the header?

Note that when @samcarter brought up the issue of the header being too small, the redesigns that were proposed did not involve elements being partially cut off.

For example, see this proposal below, which re-positions the elements and removes the dark shaded triangle. The original purpose of the dark shaded triangle was to emphasise the `{TeX}` logo, but it feels out of place once the `{TeX}` logo is no longer on top of it.

**One of the proposals by @samcarter** (see [the original discussion](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7744/128068))

[image]

Comment: Trying out a new header in production. Lemme know if this is any better! Should be a lot more clear.

Comment: @AaronShekey It is certainly better now. However, the old header was a collection of showcases and felt like it. With the newer and smaller layout the one line of examples with roughly the same baseline does not feel like a collection any more. My eyes are more drawn to it thinking the background is telling me something important ... I can see that it would be hard to get back the "collectio vibe" and at the same time preserve the size of the elements so they are recognisable in the smaller space, but maybe there is an adequate solution ...

Comment: @moewe maybe we can improve this, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7781/tex-new-site-theme-is-live#comment24165_7842

Answer (score 35):

Note: I had to upvote Mico's answer, he has a point. And actually, SE should be damn happy that this all happened after TUG AGM (TeX Users Group Annual General Meeting). If the timing was slightly different, you would very likely be mentioned there and it would *not* be a nice mention.

Just to make things clear, regular participants to TUG meetings have TeX.SE reputations (and ranks): 673k (rank 1), 461k (rank 2), 194k (rank 8 + mod), 175k (rank 12), 68k, 57k, 38k etc. You are ignoring these peoples' opinions, and note that these people gather at TUG meetings because they are of the most important developers in the current TeX world.

Honestly, as a member of TUG and a participant in the AGM, I would have proposed to the TUG Board to look into options how to migrate content from TeX.SE to a TUG hosted website. And the reason is not *this* particular change in design; it's the long-standing policy of ignoring sites' beautiful looks. I understand that SE becomes an internet Titanic, but maybe this is just another reason why to quit it before it sanks.

Answer (score 32):

## Tag curly brackets

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

I would love for the tags to get back their curly brackets, but I fear that has been struck down finally (I'll still try though).

## Tag colours

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The blue of the tags just does not fit well to the rest of the colour scheme. Would it be possible to find more suitable colours for them?

## Post-owner box colour

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The box of the question owner is also blue, again not fitting the rest of the colour scheme

[image: screenshot of a question with the question owner box in blue]

Comment: Tag colors have been addressed and should go live with the next build

Comment: @AaronShekey That is good to hear. Please do look into the question owner box as well, it would look odd if it were the last thing to stay blue around here. It is kind of hard to tell between my eyes and my monitor but a few other elements seem to be on the bluer side of grey as well.

Comment: The post owner box now inherits from the theme's primary color. I've marked this as `status-completed`

Comment: @AaronShekey Very good, thank you. I noticed that the post owner box and the tag boxes are in slightly different shades, though. Is that intentional? The upper part of the box around the avatar picture on the user page is still bluish: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg

Answer (score 26):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## Code highlighting colours

I'm happy to see that the final theme turned out less blue than I feared.

The code highlighting is blue, however, and I would love to see it back in its older, warmer colours

[image: screenshot of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444016/35864 showing code hgighlighting in blue]

Comment: Also the leading in code is too tight.

Comment: @egreg Probably safer to add a new answer about that so it doesn't get lost.

Comment: It is also in my answer.

Comment: although the blue code highlighting *is* different from black, it's harder to distinguish the difference between these two colors.  the brighter highlighting was designed that way for a purpose -- to make certain features able to be distinguished very easily.  that has been lost.

Comment: This has been merged and will go live with a fresh build.

Answer (score 26):

[status-90s-calling](/questions/tagged/status-90s-calling) [boxes-boxes-everywhere](/questions/tagged/boxes-boxes-everywhere) [look-even-tags-are-boxes](/questions/tagged/look-even-tags-are-boxes) [status-if-yahoo-can-why-shouldnt-we](/questions/tagged/status-if-yahoo-can-why-shouldnt-we) [screen-space-is-overrated](/questions/tagged/screen-space-is-overrated)

Don't forget to install our favorite Stackexchange AOL toolbar and SE! Messenger

[image]

Comment: Even they figured out back then that left column is not a good idea for a column design

Comment: Did you notice how they combined serif and sans-serif fonts? Yahoo!

Comment: *(Yes I know they are trying to make it look like Facebook,yes well done, yes you must be right, yes I'm going to a Starbucks in shame)*

Comment: *(Yes also LinkedIn, yes snappy columns are not good but they use it so it must be good yes)*

Comment: YAHOO! PREFERS VISA

Answer (score 22):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

## Boxes around everything

Is it necessary to draw hard borders boxes around everything? In most places it isn't very intrusive but particularly bad looks:

[image]

(I'm not speaking of the red box I drew to make it clear what I meant)

Comment: See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7814/ for a way to remove these borders.

Comment: @Milo I saw it in chat, but thanks anyway (also in the name of future visitors).

Comment: This is basically the first mistake every **beginner** site designer does. These guys host the most prolific coders on SO. Just amazing that they learn nothing from them.

Comment: I'm wondering why this bit of navigation has to be realised with ugly boxes while other parts happily use the much less intrusive, less annoying and less ugly tabs.

Answer (score 21):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## Too many different colour shades

I think there are too many different colour shades. Take for example this small part of the site:

[image]

It includes 3 different shades of red. The colour of the TeX logo is much brighter and the colours of the upvoted question button and the "Ask Question" button look like they ought to be the same but are slightly different - this looks odd!

---

Using a colour picker tool, I get the following colours for the elements:

- the TeX logo: 194/73/74
- Ask Question button: 159/57/61
- Upvoted button: 153/71/68

Comment: All three of those elements are colored with the exact same color value  (#B6514E). So, I think there is something of an optical illusion happening for you. Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: @JoeFriend I added the colour codes I get with a colour picker tool - I really don't think they are the same.

Comment: @JoeFriend I just inspected the .svg file of the TeX logo: The colour used there seems to be `c2494a` and not `B6514E`...

Comment: I didn't look directly at the assets or code, just measured the color on my screen. I'll check with design.

Comment: @JoeFriend Thanks for having a look into this! Something related: Is the TeX image from the old design still downloadable somewhere? The one seen in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqKX6.png

Comment: The color of the logo has been addressed, but the upvote arrows are generated programmatically based on CSS filters. They're not perfect, but they aren't too far away from our primary red highlight color. These will improve once we no longer rely on image-based sprites. For technical reasons, we'll have to wait to get the upvoted buttons the exact same shade of red.

Comment: @AaronShekey Thanks for the feedback! Good to hear the logo will be fixed. The arrows are indeed not far off.

Answer (score 20):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug)

## Badges on meta

On meta the badge seem to be missing a bit on the left

[image: screenshot of a user profile on meta, the circular badges all miss a bit on the left]

Comment: This has been fixed and should go live in the next build

Answer (score 18):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

On narrow screens, the content area is very small, on top of the site it's as low as 23%, after scrolling down it goes to 44%. That's way too low.

Either make the sidebars shrinkable or make them collapse much sooner.

Answer (score 17):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## The background colour of the content area

In the site mockup that was posted in [New TeX site theme coming soon](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/new-tex-site-theme-coming-soon), the background colour of the content area was the familiar warm colour it has always been.

**The original mockup** - posted by @JoeFriend

[image]

But, in the new site, this has been changed to white...

**The new site**

[image]

Judging by the reaction [Making the white background less white](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7788/128068) is getting in the post [Make TeX.SX look nice again!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7787/make-the-site-look-nice-again), it seems a lot of users much prefer the warm look of the original site design.

In fact, this change to a white background has arguably made the blue tags stick out more, which is what the [Tag colours post](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7784/128068) by @moewe is addressing.

Was it intentional to change this from what was being proposed to us? Because we were never consulted on this particular change.

Comment: This has been addressed and should go live in our next build

Answer (score 15):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Inconsistent square boxes?

Perhaps this is a bug? In the site mockup posted in [New TeX site theme coming soon](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/new-tex-site-theme-coming-soon), the boxes around 'answers' had rounded edges which matched the design of the other boxed elements.

**The original mockup** - posted by @JoeFriend

[image]

But in the new site, these boxes now have sharp corners?

**The new site**

[image]

Was it intentional to change this? I notice all other boxed elements have remained the same from the mockup.

### Following the update (11th August 2018)

The boxes around answers are still inconsistent. On the 'Questions' page, the boxes have been changed to have rounded edges:

[image]

But, on the 'Home' page, they have square edges:

[image]

I'm guessing this is just a bug.

Comment: This has been addressed and should go live in the next build

Comment: @AaronShekey Thanks for addressing this but just to make you aware there are still some bugs. See my update to the post.

Comment: @Milo This is now fixed for both Home and Questions.

Comment: Apart from the non-rounded corners that have been fixed meanwhile, I don’t understand why the numbers and text in the three boxes don’t align vertically. “votes“ and “views” are always a bit shifted to the top in comparison with “answers” and this is even more so when there is a border around the answers box. I just discovered this today and the more often I see this, the less I like it.

Answer (score 15):

> [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) We are working on addressing this issue. It is covered here: [Can we show new/anonymous users more Q&A?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314417/3543330)

## Unregistered vistors view

Picture worth a thousand words:

[image]

The issues:

1. **IT'S ALL BLACK!** If I came to a site with this amount of black, I would frighten away! The middle black thing is so dominant that you barely see anything else. Maybe it's the intent, to separate this message from the site's contents, but the cost is huge. Also, before the site title was large, now it's small, so the `{TeX}` logo is not even dominant to the page. This all seems very confusing and unwelcoming. **Maybe even simply reducing the main black message to the central column would lessen the blackness of this page, see below. Anyway, changing the colour would be the best.
2. There is three black blocks and three things to close: Code of Conduct, Sign in, Cookies+Privacy+ToS. I don't think anyone is gonna read any of the messages anyway. I believe that Code of Conduct should be merged into the middle or the bottom stuff, certainly for users who happen to see all three messages.
3. Please unify the link style here.

[image]

Comment: +1, but I don't know whether I agree on the code of conduct thing, because I think this is the place for "temporary"/update messages. However, the whole picture just doesn't work.

Comment: Question is whether unregistered visitors need to see the Code of Conduct message anyway. I assume it becomes more relevant once you actually contribute or sign in ...

Answer (score 14):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug)

## Fonts on meta

While the main site retained its serifs in titles, the meta site did not. It has sans serif titles. I'm not sure if that is intentional, but this certainly takes away from the "meta is greyscaled main" effect.

Comment: This has been addressed and should go live with our next build.

Answer (score 14):

[fixed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed)

## Question titles

The new titles look like they're squeezed to half there natural width. Perhaps it's just me, but it looks odd.

Comment: Any chance you can post an image of the issue. I'm not seeing it, but could be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @JoeFriend I can't see it anymore, too, as I've changed it in my userContent.css. The font the default is using just looks very narrow and is too small. I've changed it to 16px DejaVu Serif.

Comment: This should be 'fixed' now with the question titles switching over to sans serif in the light of https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7803/35864

Answer (score 13):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## Links are hard to notice

Due to the relative dark colour, links are hard to notice in posts and comments.

Here is a hidden object game for you. Who can find the link?

[image]

Comment: I must say that the underlining on meta makes links really easy to find, maybe that could be an option here that does not depart too far from the current colour scheme.

Comment: @moewe That is a great idea!

Comment: We've added underlines on all post links. I think it'll really help, especially with themes that have a primary color that doesn't differ too much from the main text color. This'll go out in the next build.

Comment: @AaronShekey Thanks for adding the underlines. They are a great feature, but I also see underlined links in the tag boxes (e.g. your status-completed badge in this post). For them (tag boxes), this seems quite redundant.

Comment: That follow up fix is on its way. :)

Comment: @AaronShekey Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13):

### Recreating the stylograph pen

I would like it to be restored the stylograph pen to which I was fond and gave a touch of class and elegance, and to eliminate the classic triangle.

Comment: While I completely agree with you that restoring the vote buttons would be great, the powers have rejected this before, because it's one of the things everyone loved…

Answer (score 13):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

## Make "Disable Responsiveness" global and persistent

By chance (and not because it was communicated in any way) I found the "Disable Responsiveness" button at the bottom of the page

[image]

- It would be nice if this would automatically apply to the whole network and one wouldn't need to press it on each site and meta site separately.
- It would also be nice to have this as option in one user preferences. Currently the setting is lost every time the browser cookies are cleared.

Comment: Thanks for this. Though disabling it does not, sadly, do all that much about the restricted space available for content generally. I don't understand the sense in which the new design is 'responsive' anyhow. Responsive to what exactly? Seems highly unresponsive to me.

Answer (score 12):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## Please make old TeX logo and voting icons available for download

This way people can modify the site with the help of user scripts etc. to fit their taste.

---

Update:

The images can be found at

- old TeX logo: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/tex/img/logo.png?v=da
- old voting buttons: http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/tex/img/sprites.svg

Comment: The voting icons are part of the sprite file which is still used for the badge icons, so they are still available. I added a script for restoring them to https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7791/80496

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Fantastic!

Comment: Backups, for posterity: https://archive.fo/xpLJH and https://archive.fo/W2583

Answer (score 11):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug)

## Comment field glow on Meta

While I can live with the blue highlighting of a currently selected text input box on the main site, on Meta the box gets highlighted with a red border with green (or blue?) glow. Please change this and while you're at it, perhaps also change the blue from the main site and other input boxes to something warmer.

Comment: A fix for this has merged and should go out in the next build.

Answer (score 11):

## Highlight colour in tool bar

The orange highlight colour when hovering with the mouse over one of the elements in the post tool bar seems out of place. Can it be replaced with the red TeX.SE color?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Consider the following with compositing (normal display):

[image: screenshot]

and without compositing:

[image: screenshot]

What do you see?

I see four large astroturf-green boxes on a beige-brown background and a black navigation bar. The background is mostly empty, but there's some stuff which might be meaningful, but is obviously of relatively little importance.

The page is trying to tell me something about or with the bright green boxes. Aside from suggesting what colour scheme I should avoid at all costs, it isn't clear what this message is. Nothing else leaps out: nothing interesting, engaging or intriguing.

The boxes a bit glarey, so the page bothers my eyes a bit, though I realise they must be very, very important to the site. Far more important than anything else. That's a bit weird and there's the glare, so I really just want to leave now or, if at all possible, sooner.

I don't know if this is the message SE wants me to find here. Perhaps it is. But that is the message the site currently sends, and that message dominates everything else, even though I don't know what it is.

But I'm gone by now, of course, to somewhere with a more comfortable feel to it which offers something intriguing, engaging or interesting to explore or read or do.

Welcome to the world wide web.

Comment: Something is odd about the "votes" column in the screenshot, it is not coloured for me. And the site seems to be weirdly transparent...

Comment: @moewe The transparency might be the result of a compositor at work (on my Linux machine unfocused windows also show some transparency).

Comment: @TeXnician That might well be it. In that case I feel the screenshot might be a bit unfair, since the site can't control the content behind it, which seems to add a few odd visual effects here (the mentioned votes column, the barely visible text behind, the colour scheme probably also suffers from the transparency my first impression was that things are darker than on my screen).

Comment: Well, the votes column looks like normal white for me (being used to compositors), but the overall impression that the green boxes are pretty dominant is shown in the picture (in my opinion).

Comment: It is kinda weird they draw  your eye to the answered questions, rather than ones you've tagged interest in or that are unanswered.

Comment: @moewe I've added a screenshot with compositing turned off. However, compositing is extremely common, so the view with it is relevant, although the shot provides what is admittedly only the display with one particular compositor and set of configuration options. I don't think it makes much difference, except the one without hurts my eyes more.

Comment: @AzorAhai Yes. And that a question is answered is way more important that what the question is. So, even if I'm looking for answers rather than questions to answer, it is still very odd.

Comment: A fortnight already and this isn't even tagged 'declined'.

Answer (score 10):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## Colour of "cancel" button

The blue colour of the "cancel" button seems odd (now that we finally god rid of all the other blue elements - thank a lot for the update!). I suggest to make it black or gray.

[image]

Comment: Don't you find the green boxes worse? The blue was bad, but the green is horrible.

Comment: @cfr Sorry, I don't think I can follow. Which green boxes?

Comment: I mean the ones indicating an accepted answer. For me, at least, they dominate the page in lists of questions.

Comment: @cfr Ah, yes. I found the colour too ugly so I changed it to something a bit more tuned down. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7813/36296

Comment: This button is now inheriting the proper theme color

Comment: @AaronShekey Thanks a lot for fixing this!

Answer (score 10):

The only buttons that bring you back to the "home" place are in the left column, whereas all people work with is in the main column (well, do you still consider it "main"?)

Please, add some way in the main column to navigate back to [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com) when you are viewing a question. Before, there was no need to navigate away from the central column, and that was actually a nice feature.

[image]

Comment: Well, they have one way: `g`→`h` with keyboard shortcuts enabled.

Comment: Also, the menu hidden behind the SE logo in the top-right.

Comment: @Raphael That's still away from the main column, though. I'm surprised by this. I thought if anything a new design would aim to make it easy to navigate back, which has always been annoyingly slow-going on SE. But no, they actually managed to make it even harder.

Comment: @cfr Myself, I don't usually navigate "back" to the main page. For literal "back", I'd use browser functions. For "larger" jumps, I'm happy with the top-right drop-down; it's a default place to go to, no matter whether I want to go to main, meta, or another site. Plus, it sticks with me when I scroll so it's always there when I need it. (A huge part of why I think the left bar is mostly useless is that I almost never use those links, including Home.)

Comment: @Raphael I want the view I got from the 'Questions' tab at the top, which now in the list. I can't access that directly from the right menu. It makes it 2 clicks not 1. I hardly ever view the home page with 'Top Questions'. I always want 'Questions'.

Answer (score 9):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

Reviewing the Low Quality Posts with Google Crome on Wimdows 10 I get this:

[image]

But if I shift the bar to make the other options on the top right appear, I get this:

[image]

The text of the post is shifted but the buttons don't show up.

Comment: Do you see this on the [completed review item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/154777)? I'm having a hard time reproducing since y'all keep the queues pretty clean. ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson I saw it when it still was in the queue, thanks.

Comment: Ok. I'll see if I can reproduce in a dev environment so I don't have to sit on review. :-)

Comment: I can't reproduce on dev and it doesn't seem like the problem is on the close queue for me. Are you seeing it on the close vote queue?

Comment: @JonEricson I hid the left navigation. With it hidden, the close vote queue is OK. Now I re-enable it, I'll answer you as soon as there's something in the queue.

Comment: @JonEricson The close vote queue works, even with the left navigation enabled.

Comment: @JonEricson I got the same problem on the Review Reopen Votes, but only in IE, Crome is OK,

Answer (score 9):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## Title background

[We asked about this before](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7744/11002), but you seem to have missed that one (it got marked as [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) almost a month ago, but nothing happened), so I repost the request here:

Please, do something about the title background. It does not make *any* sense as it is now. To make clear what I mean, here is a high contrast version of the spot:

[image]

It used to be well thought and well designed, now it is not. I see two options:

1. Ask the community for new ideas on how this should look like. However, seeing how you ignore people's opinions, I'm not sure they will be willing to pu any effort into this.
2. Remove the thing altogether, as zero quality is more than negative quality.

Comment: "nothing happened" is not fair. Compared to the mockup they changed the size (which is good) by cropping the image which now shows the empty space between the two lines so none of the nice elements is really visible any more (not good). But I'm not complaining, this leaves more room to add ducks.

Comment: Assuming that cropping only occurs at pixel boarders, they had 282 possibilities to crop the image and still managed to find the worst possible place. That's quite an achievement!

Comment: Take a look at the version that is live now. Please provide your feedback. Thanks.

Comment: @JoeFriend Looks better, thanks.

Comment: @JoeFriend I think it looks better than before (with most things being cut off), but it has significantly lost its feel. The old background was clearly a collection of showcases, but the new one looks more ordered and aligned and does not give of this "collection vibe", it comes over as more dominant now ...

Comment: @JoeFriend The new background is really a big improvement! Thanks a lot for listening to our feedback! Proposal: Once the whole new site roll-out and bug fixes settle down, would it be possible to make a contest and see what suggestions our tex.se community has for background images and if you like what we come up with, you could use it as background image? [I don't propose this to add ducks(\*), I think this could be a good way to restore some bonds between our community and the design --  (\* at least not too many :)]

Comment: @samcarter Yes that's something we would be willing to work with the community on.

Comment: @JoeFriend Good to hear!

Answer (score 8):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## Tab colours

With the new non-white background colour (thank you for that change!) the "tabs" for sorting questions or in the review queue don't integrate seamless into the rest of the page any more. They are still white.

One could argue that this is intended for tags that are not selected since they stand out from the background that way, but it looks odd for the active tab, which looks like it should be connected seamlessly to the content below it (it has no lower border).

[image: Tabs to sort answers]

the effect is more visible if the background colour is a bit darker:

[image: Tabs to sort answers with background colour turned to pink so the effect is more pronounced]

(added by @Milo) Note the problem also occurs on your user profile page:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would also be nice if the orange stackoverflow colour of the active tab would be replaced with our red colour.

Comment: @samcarter Actually, I quite like the orange, but given that the left sidebar is red and that on meta at least the tabs aren't orange either, this is definitely worth a look. Consistency seems more important here than my fondness for orange.

Comment: This has been fixed. Selected tab colors now inherit the theme's primary color.

Comment: @AaronShekey If one hovers over the tab the line still becomes orange. Would it be possible to use the lighter red, which is used for hovering over normal links?

Comment: @AaronShekey Thank you. I second samcarter's comment that the orange on hover looks a bit odd.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the selected tab needs _any_ hover state at all, and that's how we plan to handle our tabs in the future. I'll kill the hover state here. On it!

Comment: The hover state on the selected tab no longer highlights on our unified themes. This'll go live in the next build.

Comment: @AaronShekey While it is true that the upper boarder no longer changes colour on hovering, the background of the tab still switches colour from the background colour of our site in normal state to white if hovering.

Comment: @AaronShekey Additionally to samcarters observation above I also noticed that the mouse pointer treats the active tab as not clickable (i.e. it stays an arrow and does not become a hand on Windows), which might be right, but looks a bit odd to me.

Comment: @AaronShekey See this comparison between hovering and not hovering: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Arfa.png

Comment: @AaronShekey Actually, the thing is even more confusing because at least here the active tab is clickable and jumps back to an anchor on the page. So I really think it makes sense to get the hand back.

Answer (score 8):

## Hide tag-excerpt in the active question list

Please hide the tag excerpt on the active question tab of a tag, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblatex?sort=active

These information are accessible via the tag-info tab. Maybe the current behaviour is good for new users, but once a user has a certain amount of reputation or a badge for this tag, it seems like a waste of space to display it every single time.

[image]

Comment: The "Learn more ..." link leads to the same tag wiki site as the "Info" button in the "Info/New/Frequent/Votes/Active/Unanswered" navigation that seems a bit redundant as well. Plus I believe that the big "Watch Tag" and "Ignore Tag" buttons a just a tad too large.

Comment: The matter of wasted space by tag info and this entire block has also been brought up at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28851

Comment: @moewe Interesting thread! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 8):

## Answer/votes/views boxes not aligned

The problem of the not rounded borders of the answers boxes has been solved already. But what is even more annoying to me is the fact that these boxes are not at all aligned vertically. See the following picture that illustrates the problem:

[image]

While “votes” and “views” are aligned, the text “answers” is shifted downwards a bit and another bit if there is a border around this box (i.e. if there is at least one answer). This is not only a problem on this site, but, as far as I can see, it appears on other SX pages as well that already use the new theme. The effect also appears in the questions tab of the user’s activity page.

The problem can be solved quite easily by setting the padding of all three boxes to the same value via CSS (but consider the border that adds another 2px!).

Comment: Three years later, the "votes" box is still not aligned to its neighbors ...

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if this is a problem with the new theme (not many questions here have so many answers that sorting is really needed)  but I just realized that you can only sort answers so  that the oldest answer is on top. I find this odd as normally if I sort by date I'm interested in what's new and don't want to have to scroll all the page down first.

[image]

Comment: "Active" give you the newest answer (of course it takes into account edits as well). But this seems to be the same for the old theme as well

Comment: @moewe yes active is a work around but not the same as newest due to the edits. At best I would like if "oldest" would be "date" and would switch between both directions.

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Please, remove the serif fonts in titles (and everywhere), they simply do not fit in.

Comment: Is this answer ironically missing a 'sans'?

Comment: @AlanMunn I see a serif font here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7kJ2.png

Comment: Yes, but I thought we wanted that. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7748/2693

Comment: @AlanMunn That's an opinion I strongly do not share.

Comment: Seems like a matter of taste that will not be resolved to everyone's satisfaction.

Comment: I do like my serif fonts, but since some apparently unchangeable network-wide bits on this page are in sans serif (in particular the "All Questions", " Tags", "Questions tagged" headings and the side bar) I feel that the mix of sans serif and serif does not look slick any more, it has become a weird mixture with no real motivation. I vote to leave the serifs off completely.

Comment: Just to add that in the old design the sans-serif/serif dichotomy was motived: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/638/ shows clearly that heading-like content was serif while body-level content was sans serif. This has been lost with the advent of the unchangeable side-wide sans serif and simply does not work any more.

Comment: @JonEricson The original request for more serifs Alan referred to was actually asking for serifs in places where the new design does not seem to allow them (at least that is how I read the responses we got and the result we have obtained so far), I'm quite sure that the consensus is that the current mix of sans serif and serif on this site looks odd at best. In particular I believe that this misunderstanding should not be used as a reason to ignore this area completely citing a matter of taste where not everyone can be pleased.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree. I was assuming that the main site was still using a serifed font when I made my comment, but if the main font has to be sans serif, then having a mixture is simply not good. And since this is a site dedicated to good typography, it's really bad to have such a clash.

Comment: We've unified on sans serif here.

Comment: @AaronShekey Good. Thank you. I'm sad to see the serifs gone, but I think that was the sensible decision in this situation.

Comment: Well, the "sensible" would be keeping more serif fonts and more per-site features. This is simple the "less bad".

Answer (score 5):

*This seems to have been fixed in the course of revisiting links for https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7832/35864*

## Border below images

On meta links are marked with an underline (which I personally quite like, this is definitely an option that could be explored re the links on the main site, which are hard to notice at times https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7832/35864). Since images are usually included with a link here that means that images have a "bottom border" now, which looks odd

[image: screenshot of a question on this site with an image, a pixeled border runs along the bottom of the image]

Comment: Thanks for using a very good picture to demonstrate this :)

Answer (score 4):

I actually like the new layout because the avatars and screen shots look now soooo much better in comparison. ;-)

Comment: Although this is intended as a joke I have no doubts that it will be used disingenuously to "prove" that some people like the new layout.

Answer (score 4):

## Missing line below all tabs with a count badge

The faint gray line below all inactive tabs with a blue count badge is missing for zoom levels unequal to 100% (both smaller and higher zoom level)

[image]

As long as I hover over the tab, the line is visible again (see the "favorites" tab in the picture below):

[image]

Comment: On my Firefox 61.0.2 tabs with counts are fine border-wise. But sometimes I get the grey line to extend below the active tab as well. I can't really reproduce this consistently, just now I see the line in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/231729/35864 but not in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: @moewe I tried a few things and realised that this only happens with zoom levels != 100%

Answer (score 1):

Why don't make the page like an IDE (integrated development environment, such as Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, any Video editing software, Adobe Illustrator, etc) in which users can freely change the look and feel of their work-space by hiding, showing, enabling, disabling, activating, deactivating, adding, removing, docking, undocking, repositioning  the tool windows, menus,  font colors, font type, style-sheet, skins, etc such that users and the developers are always happy with their own decision?