# Text line spacing for questions and answers

Tags: discussion, answers, questions, new-features

Just out of mere curiosity, but I wanted to know if the line spacing of the text has been increased because I didn't notice the difference this morning.

[image]

The image is taken from: [Defining a bibstyle and citestyle for autocite footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560167/defining-a-bibstyle-and-citestyle-for-autocite-footnote)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, line spacing has been increased as mentioned here on Meta Stack Exchange: [New post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353446/295232)

Many people don't like the change, and posts like [Please revert the line-height change!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353525/295232) and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353529/295232) are very popular right now.

Answer (score 3):

I've added an answer to our [Make TeX.SX look nice again!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7787/2693) question showing how to adjust the line spacing to something more readable.

- [Adjusting the line spacing](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8653/2693)

Comment: I have upvoted this and the other https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8653/2693. Thank you lot lot.