# Comments on the new site design

Tags: discussion

The page asking for comments on the new site design is so heavily downvoted that it doesn't appear on the Active Meta page, nor does it appear in the Hot meta questions. It intermittently appears on the Featured on Meta for reasons that aren't quite clear.

If we upvote this question, we can make this question appear.

Here's the link:

- [TeX new site theme is live](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7781/2693)

Please don't post your comments on the site design here.

Comment: The question already appears in the Community Bulletin, under Featured on Meta -- which is the most visible thing that can happen to a meta post. No fake votes are needed.

Comment: @user69318 Fair enough. It still doesn't appear on the Active meta questions, which is where casual meta visitors might see it.

Comment: @user69318 What do you mean? I don't see it in the "Featured on Meta" sidebar (either on meta or on the main site): https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB7iC.png And of course I don't see it on the front page of https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ (even though it's recent enough).

Comment: @AlanMunn Something from a few minutes has changed: the color of the code and the button Ask question.

Comment: I see it under the 'Active' tab, but it isn't a featured Meta question any more, as @ShreevatsaR said.

Comment: If you click on 'Questions' in the left side-bar, the 'Active' tab lists the question. If you go to the home Meta page, the 'Active' tab doesn't. Something is screwy somewhere, but then, something is screwy everywhere.