# Ragged alignment of question titles on main page

Tags: discussion, design

#### update January 18, 2019

Yesterday or so I first noticed this issue seemed to have been solved (possibly network-wide). It my have been so for weeks.

I don't know where to link to, if that issue has been discussed elsewhere on the network. With this information added, I guess that question can be closed. Ah no sorry, I confused with issue trackers. So if an answer linking to suitable network resources is provided I shall check its correctness and validity and validate the answer (despite my incomptence in all things CSS and JavaScript).

---

---

Screenshot with added red line (which I tried to make vertical):

[image]

The left alignment is deficient.

Is it a site problem?

---

As reported in comments, (initially triggered by this additional image:)

[image: two lines]

at least the amount of additional indentation seems to be decided by the styling of the number of answers: the shortest is "1 answer" (whether it has been accepted or not), then "0 answers" is wider although unframed, and "2 (or more) answers" is even wider due to its framing (be it filled or not).

On `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/` the layout is vertical, and I perceive no raggedness, did not check thoroughly though. The horizontal layout of `https://tex.stackexchange.com/` is an ingredient of this issue.

---

As pointed out in comment by @samcarter, this is network-wide problem as one can see at `meta.stackexchange.com`.

[image]

Comment: It's similar in my browser. It seems to occur if either the title is long enough to linebreak, or if the tags part is so long that it would overlap with the author part

Comment: @siracusa I do not see (from cursory examination) an obvious rule. With [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dow6L.png) for example. ah wait silly me, in that example the "accepted" style shifts things to the right...

Comment: "0 answers" (sic) shifts more than "1 answer" and less than "2 answers".

Comment: You are right, there's a slight shift depending on the number of answers given so far. But it's definitely worst for me when the title is too long and there's no proper point to break it

Comment: @siracusa in my browser I seem to have some difficulty reproducing issue you experience with long titles...

Comment: @jfbu Unrelated to the problem, just curiosity: would you really use singular for `0 answers`?

Comment: @samcarter *yes*, I <strike>won't</strike> *would use singular*, but I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: @jfbu I'm not a native speaker either, but I would use singular only for +1. Interesting how this differs between people :)

Comment: @samcarter perhaps in English one says "he gave no answers", but in French I would write "il ne donna pas de réponse" (singular)

Comment: @jfbu https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1131 seems to an interesting categorization of this phenomena.

Comment: @samcarter excellent, thanks!

Comment: @jfbu After I learned something new about languages, back to the topic: I just tested on meat.stackexchange.com and I think there is the same problem, so I guess this a network-wide bug.

Comment: Vaguely related problem about horizontal alignment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7856/36296

Comment: @samcarter any luck I get some bucks (not ducks) for having discovered a NETWORK-WIDE BUG! ??!!

Comment: @samcarter do you think my question should actually figure as an answer to https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7781/4686?

Comment: @jfbu If there would be bucks for networkwide bugs, many people would be rich after the new design was introduced :)

Comment: @jfbu Not sure if moving this to https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7781/4686 would help. After a few quick fixed right after new theme roll-out it now seems to be ignored by stackexchange ... just my personal impression, maybe I see this too negative

Comment: @samcarter I am generous and ready to share wealth on this bug-discovery.

Comment: @jfbu :) you should make a feature request about bucks for finding bugs!

Comment: @samcarter thanks for pointing to my comment. It is indeed related, altough my comment was rather regarding the vertical alignment. I guess, the boxes for votes, answers and views are just styled in a way, that their contents as well as borders affect their sizes. Hope this will be fixed soon. =)

Comment: As this is a network-wide issue, has this been asked on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ ? More people may see it there, and it may have a higher chance of getting fixed.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR no, I have not asked there, because I don't like so much the treatment I received in the past when I asked about hiding all reputation and badges...