# How to set up viewing preferences to automatically exclude postings of certain specific users?

Tags: discussion, users

Just as it is possible to automatically *highlight* postings if they are "tagged" with various keywords, it is also possible to *ignore* postings if their tags are on a user-specified "ignore list".

**Question**: Is it possible to set up a user-specified "ignore list" not based on the postings' tags but based on who posted the queries?

Some background to this question: While this site is, overall, remarkably free of trolls and spammers, once in a while a user persists in posting poorly phrased and unclear questions -- and then is remarkably very quick to respond aggressively and challenge anyone who dares to point out that their postings are less than clear with over-the-top aggressive language. Such a user frequently has no qualms of accusing anyone of trolling, bias, lack of decency, and worse.

I've learned the hard way that trying to engage such users politely and attempting to have a productive discussion is utterly useless. Indeed, such engagements should be avoided entirely as they meet the criterion of the (originally Italian?) piece of advice, "Don't wrestle with a pig -- you get dirty, and the pig enjoys the wrestling match."

Ideally, there should be a method to enable me (and others) to place all queries posted by pig-type users on an "automatic ignore" list. Does this site provide such a method, or can it be created without too much knowledge of html programmming?

Comment: Yes, if such an option exists, it will allow you to escape from those users. And everyone could do the same. Yet I am wondering at which point it becomes a case for the moderators, who could simply remove the post and ban that user. This might have advantages and disadvantages. A disadvantage is that some may call this censorship, an advantage that other users may not have to get exposed to these conversations.

Comment: +1! If this option doesn't exist, they should invent it! (Btw, I don't think the criterion is Italian, but perfectly matches with someone @marmot and I are thinking of). P. S. = This way I wouldn't have to check my do-not-answer-to-this-one list!

Comment: I guess your proposal has been discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/399040) on the "main" meta site.

Comment: I very much agree with @marmot.  It is either a case for the moderators or you just have to withstand the rudeness.  Just look over to Twitter and the level of discourse there.  You'll find that people are only communicating with their self-made filter bubbles, treating everyone else as enemy.  Therefore -1.

Comment: @HenriMenke - Just so I understand your downvote (better): What exactly about my posting prompted your downvote? Put differently, what about my question, "Is it possible to set up a user-specific 'ignore list' not based on the postings' tags but based on who posted the queries?" is so bad? I'd like to understand your viewpoint better. Incidentally, (a) I don't use Twitter *at all*, for several reasons, and (b) why would the claim that things are better here than over on Twitter justify not providing an additional intervention tool to those who desire to have one?

Comment: @marmot - My query in no way implies that one should not feel free to contact the moderators and ask them to intervene, e.g., by banning one or more users. On the other hand, why not provide users  an easy and straightforward method for ignoring all queries posted by problem users?

Comment: @Mico I don't think blocking other users is solving any problem.  It has actually adverse effects, driving the blocked parties further apart.  Even though you are skillfully phrasing your question, I read between the lines that you are asking for such a feature, with which I strongly disagree.

Comment: @HenriMenke Moderators are too good, imho. There have been cases, which moderators know, where a user should have been banned for a while, but no action was taken - as far as I know.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I don't know how bans work on the moderator level, what implications these have, and what restrictions apply.  It would be interesting to know though.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, this secrecy about ban rules is quite annoying. I perfectly understand privacy problems, but a bit more disclosure wouldn't be bad.

Comment: Are you talking about a *permanent* ignore, or a time-limited ignore?

Comment: @Johannes_B - I actually hadn't thought the time-limit aspect yet; I suppose I was thinking mostly about a permanent criterion. However, a time-limited ignore (with a limit of 3 to 4 weeks, say) would be fine too. In my experience, the "pigs" quickly figure out when no-one in a given group is willing to rise to their flame bait anymore; at that point, i.e., when they can no longer count on getting a rise out of annoying and tormenting group members, they find other groups to move on to... In all likelihood, they pigs will be long gone by the 4-week mark.

Comment: @CarLaTeX - Interesting that the saying isn't necessarily of Italian origin. I honestly can't remember when I heard the saying the very first time, but I may have learned it from an Italian person. Naturally, that doesn't make the saying Italian...

Comment: @Mico Perhaps it is from Southern Italy, I don't know, in Milan I have never heard it :)

Comment: https://quoteinvestigator.com/2017/07/08/pig/

Comment: @Johannes_B Definitely not Italian, thanks for sharing :):):)

Comment: + 1000000000 if I could! I had an ignore user user script in the past, unfortunately the new site design broke it and I observe a noticeable effect: I was much more related if I don't see the posts of some specific users.

Comment: @HenriMenke - You wrote, "[The blocking rule] has actually adverse effects, driving the blocked parties further apart." This claim would appear to rest on an invalid premise, viz., that the to-be-blocked party has any intention of engaging in a constructive conversation. Once a thoroughly disagreeable user has started to spew venom and discord, he/she has already driven the parties mighty far apart. I do not see why blocking such a user would drive the parties apart *further*. The only real effect of the blocking tool is salutary: to make it easier for normal users to ignore the pig-users.

Comment: @marmot - According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309160/280525) to the meta query [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/280525), to which you provided a link to earlier today, as of 17 April 2018 the site's powers-that-be are said to be *considering* providing a blocking rule of the type I've expressed some interest in. I suppose that's mildly encouraging. Of course, who knows how much longer it's going to be until such a rule is actually made available...

Comment: On reflection, I think it's a good idea. By not answering the questions of some contributors, it will allow other contributors to answer them and learn LaTeX.

Comment: Your quote is attributed to [George Bernard Shaw](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/george_bernard_shaw_137450) at least in English.  But I'm slightly sceptical, because for falsely attributed quotes he's up there with Oscar Wilde and Abraham Lincoln (who of course said "The problem with internet quotes is that you can't always depend on their accuracy")

Comment: +1; BTW, are you still on boycott? (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7781/tex-new-site-theme-is-live/7799#7799)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - It's not a fully boycott, but I sure spend much less time on TeX.SE than I used to. On most days, I answer no more than 2 queries, whereas I regularly answered 5 or more before the change was imposed.

Comment: That's a loss for the community. Hope you spend the time in a good way.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - Thanks, yes, I'm doing just fine. :-)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - As of today, I'm no longer on boycott -- I just asked the site administrators earlier today to delete my profile entirely. I was informed that the delete will go into effect in the next 24 hours or so. Best, Mico.

Comment: @Mico See LinkedIn :). That is a very big loss for the community in my point of view.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner  - Thank you for your very kind words. I very much appreciate them.

Comment: I agree with @Dr.ManuelKuehner.  This really is a loss. You and I have helped so many users with our `bibtex` answers (among other things). I'll miss the help.

Comment: @AlanMunn -- Many thanks for your exceedingly kind words. Incidentally, I've always very much enjoyed and learned a lot from your great answers.

Comment: @Mico Is there a way to revert your decision?

Comment: @Mico farewell, thanks for the time you spent here!

Comment: I fervently hope this is not a definitive decision.

Comment: @egreg - The decision *is* definitive. It's been coming on for a long time -- ever since last summer, when TeX.SE's wondrously charming look and feel was sanitized by the site's powers that be, ostensibly in the name of consistency with the look and feel of other sites. I've still not recovered from that event. These last few months, I was hanging on by a thread, barely, determined to "make it" until I achieved the 300k rep mark, which was probably going to happen later this summer. However, another gratuitous downvote, received this morning, snapped that thread.

Comment: @Skillmon - Thanks so much!!

Comment: @egreg - I've learned and amazing amount not only about TeX and LaTeX from you, but also about poise and, yes, displaying humor and wit. You are the rock of this site.

Comment: So, please, take some time off, but avoid deleting.

Comment: @egreg - I've been informed that my postings won't be deleted; they'll just show up as having been created by 'user5001'. I'm glad I was able to contribute solutions to quite a few queries these past 8+ years, and I will gladly state again that I learned so much about TeX, LaTeX, and friends in the process. Sadly, I never really recovered from the overbearing and insulting actions of the site admins last summer, and I don't want my name to be associated any longer with TeX.SE or any other StackExchange site.

Comment: @Mico That's very sad news.

Comment: @egreg - Just a quick note to let you know that, in the end, the very kind expressions you and others provided made me reconsider my decision. :-)

Comment: @Mico now I’ very happy! 

Answer (score 11):

I would find some kind of ignore/mark user functionality incredibly helpful primarily to make enforcing my personal do-not-answer-to-this-one (to use the the nice name @CarLaTeX invented) list easier, which is important because this is the only real lever(*) I have for users who (in my personal opinion) do something wrong.

(*comments and downvotes don't really have any effect, they are often just ignored)

## Why an ignore/mark functionality cannot be replaced by moderator actions or bans?

There are three kinds of users who end up on my do-not-answer-to-this-one list

- users who ask question after question without upvoting or accepting the nice answers they got to their previous questions. I usually leave a comment below their previous questions explaining how and why to accept an answer and if I encounter this user again and no answers have been accepted (or some other reaction, like the answer does not solve the problem because xyz) I add these users to my list because this shows that these users don't appreciate the time and effort we put into answering their question
- users who continue to post questions without MWE even after having been asked to do so multiple times
- some other triggers, which can be summarised as "users who don't appreciate that others sacrifice their spare time to help them for free" (this is a bit vague, but various strange things happened which don't fit into a narrow category)

This clearly shows that not all behaviour that (in my personal opinion) is incorrect behaviour of users is something that mods can help. Not accepting answers, ignoring comments etc. is all perfectly in agreement with the rules of this site, it is just something I personally don't like and I think the other options provided by the site (commenting and voting) are not as strong as not answering questions of this special kinds of users.

> Luckily this only affects a tiny fraction of the users. From the 145 000 users of tex.se I have 22 on do-not-answer-to-this-one list

## Experience with ignore/mark user functionality

22 names sounds not so much, but with cryptic user names like user123456789 (dummy example) they are nevertheless hard to remember. Therefore I used a browser addon in the past, which would mark posts from users on my list with a red rule so I can easily notice.

[image]

(The addon I previously used was https://bures.io/products/favorite-users/stack-exchange/, unfortunately the new "responsive" site design broke it and it no longer works for questions and causes various formatting issues)

The main effect was that I was much more relaxed. My default assumption was that every user was well behaved unless the post had a red rule besides it and if the question itself was reasonable posted it should have an answer. This made spending time on tex.se much more enjoyable.

Now in the post <del>apocalyptic</del> new design world, there is this constant subconscious fear that I might be giving answers to users from my do-not-answer-to-this-one list (which is probably my own fault because I'm often too lazy to check each and every user name if it is on my list).

## Reasons against an ignore/mark user functionality

I see two main reasons why this is a bad idea

- the philosophy of stackexchange always was that all actions (voting, answering etc.) should be based on the post itself and not the user, that all users should be treated equally. IMHO The Powers That Be broke this rule themselves by these "new user" warnings signs in triple occurrence, so I don't consider this a valid reason anymore
- the mission is larger than answering the question of a given user -- the aim is to also build a database of knowledge for future users. I think this is a valid concern. Personally I would therefore prefer a way to mark users instead of completely hiding the questions, then one could make exceptions if a question sounds useful enough for future users.

Comment: +1, I totally agree!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Especially with the name of the list?

Comment: Also if you call it pig list :):):)

Comment: You can maybe use a rewrite rule to change any username on the exclusion list to `NONONONO` or something. This should be much easier to code.

Comment: @Johan This would probably work, unfortunately writing something like this exceeds my user script knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

This does not address the question itself, but my opinion regarding this *feature request*.

---

I also have a list of *special ones* and when i encounter a question of one of these users I think *Ah, it's you again*.

But i don't just ignore them if i have the time.

Imagine a high-school teacher or university professor would ignore a student just because he is a pain in the `\ldots`.

We have to at least *try* to treat everyone with respect. In real life and in this limited internet part of (real) life.

Comment: I admire your attitude. But I don't think the teacher analogy works that well: It is a teacher's job to teach and deliberately ignoring children they have been assigned to teach would indeed be an issue. But people on this site are here as a hobby and should be allowed much more freedom to do what makes them happy. I also don't think it is nearly as rude to ignore someone's question on this site as compared to, say, someone coming up to you in the street. I wholeheartedly agree with your last paragraph.

Comment: @moewe I ignored people in real life and told them to get away when i didn't have the time. Perfectly ok i think. But it needs to be time-limited. People don't rot away in jails forever, even they get a second chance.

Comment: Exactly, my point was that in the context of this site it would be 'even more OK' to ignore people than in real life because here they do not come specifically to you and there can be no real expectation that *you* would have to deal with them or their issue. As for second chances, I don't disagree.

Comment: @moewe To be clear: I am perfectly fine with ignoring questions or tags. But not based on the fact *who* is posting the question.

Comment: I'm ignoring questions by (imo, of course) rude or unfair users. I have not much time to spend here, I prefer use it    helping other people. Btw, there was also a person who was cancelled from the list because his/her behavior changed.

Answer (score 5):

I have slightly different view from what may be read between the lines in your post and the existing answers. Certainly it is not up to me to tell you what measures you may or may not implement to ignore users. However, if I understand your request correctly you feel disturbed (or even harassed) by the behavior of certain users. As I said, I do think that it is your right to automatically ignore such users.

On the other hand, who do you think will stand up to those if not high-reputation users like you?

I personally would like to argue, thus going to some extent into the direction of [Henri Menke's comments](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8025/how-to-set-up-viewing-preferences-to-automatically-exclude-postings-of-certain-s#comment25200_8025), that, as long we do not have clear rules that prevent users from misbehaving in the way you describe, it is our job to micromanage these issues by contradicting them in comments, of course without using inappropriate wording and so on. Given [this post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/), I do not think we should dump this entirely on the moderators, unless they tell us we should not interfere.

My opinion is not very strong, but I would like to argue that if these rogue users do not get moderated by ourselves, meaning in particular by the more senior users, then this may send unfortunate signals to those who are considering to contribute more to this site.

Comment: You asked, "Who do you think will stand up to those if not high-reputation users like you?" I have no idea, and I officially no longer care. As of some time later today, or maybe tomorrow morning, my rep count will be exactly zero, as I've asked the site administrators to delete my profile on TeX.SE and all other StackExchange sites. I received another gratuitous downvote earlier today, and I decided right there and then it was going to be the very last downvote I'd *ever* receive on this site.

Comment: @Mico Sorry to hear about your decision! Let me stress, however, that I did not downvote any of your posts.

Comment: @marmot - Many thanks for your kind words and support.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a side note: This quite comes to our policies which are not quite what The Powers encourage. The standard procedure for poor posts is (1) downvote, (2) wait for edit and improvent, (3) undownvote and possibly upvote. Users with repeated negative scoring get banned eventually.

As we don't like downvotes, the balance of the ban algorithm is off. I'm quite sure I know about specific users here that would have been banned a long time ago, given we had used to follow the standard voting procedure.

I don't have a solution really, this is just a related observation, too long for a comment).